# to store form data in sessions using classes and objects php

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I have class which is used to insert the 'id' in the table using PDO connection and now i have to store form data i.e id in session variable .

```
    <?php
    session_start(); 
    // this class is used to create connection with database
    class Database
    {
        private $db_host = ‘localhost’; 
        private $db_user = ‘root’; 
        private $db_pass = ‘root’; 
        private $db_name = ‘test’;   


        public function connect()   {               
          $db = new PDO('mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8mb4', '$db_user', '$db_pass');           
          }
    }


  this class is used to insert the id in the table 

    class table1 extends Database
    {
           public function insert_info() 
            {
                    $sql = "insert into info(id) values ('?')";
                    $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
                    $sql->execute();
                    return true;
            }
    }

    $_SESSION['campid']='camp1001';
    $db = new table1();       // it is used to object of class table1.
    $res=$db->insert_info();

    ?>
```

How to store session variable in table how it will be achieved .

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass the `$_SESSION['campid']` value to `insert_info()` method?

```
$_SESSION['campid']='camp1001';
$db = new table1();       // it is used to object of class table1.
$res=$db->insert_info($_SESSION['campid']);
```

and the function

```
class table1 extends Database
{
       public function insert_info($id) // <-- add function param
        {
                $sql = "insert into info(id) values ('?')";
                $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
                $sql->execute();
                return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the session to the method. Like passing a variable to a function.

```
$_SESSION['campid']='camp1001';
$db = new table1();       // it is used to object of class table1.
$res=$db->insert_info($_SESSION['campid']);

class table1 extends Database
    {
           public function insert_info($id) 
            {
                    $sql = "insert into info(id) values ('?')";
                    $sql->bind_param("s", $id);
                    $sql->execute();
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

or pass the session value to the constructor. This will make a longer but it has it uses in certain occassions.

```
$db = new table1($_SESSION['campid']);
$res=$db->insert_info();

class table1 extends Database
    {
        public $id;   
            __construct($id){
                $this->id = $id;
            }
            public function insert_info() 
            {
                    $sql = "insert into info(id) values ('?')";
                    $sql->bind_param("s", $this->id);
                    $sql->execute();
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Whether to use $id in construct() or in insert_info() depends what the model is used for. When model is used for mirroring table, then I think the parameter should be included in method call. When model represents a record (row) in database table, then use $id in constructor.